# Tweepy Code Works in Pycharm, but not when Uploaded to Heroku

Tags: heroku, twitter, unicode, tweepy

To staart, I am pretty new to coding and this is somewhat of a big project for me. I am trying to make a twitter bot that would run automatically, however, I keep getting "Unicode objects are not escapbable" as a result when running it on a Heroku sever.

The code works fine in Pycharm, but for some reason will not work when running on Heroku. Here is what the beginning looks like:

```
import tweepy
import statsapi
import time
import os
#enviroment variables
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
#Keys
CONSUMER_KEY = os.getenv("CONSUMER_KEY")
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET")
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')
#
while True:
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020114/failed-to-send-request-only-unicode-objects-are-escapable-got-none-of-type-cl)

Comment: You need to use `heroku config:set CONSUMER_KEY=blah` and `heroku config:set CONSUMER_SECRET=blah` and `heroku config:set ACCESS_TOKEN=blah` and `heroku config:set ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=blah` to configure the environment variables for heroku

Comment: @Smitop Do I have to type in my actual keys to the config or can I use my .env file